# Medoo php sql - change search term

Tags: php, mysql, medoo

i am using the "medoo"-php/mysql-class (http://www.medoo.in) for my latest project. I like the quiet easy way to work with my SQL-stuff.

But i wondered if it is possible to change the search term according to an option from an input-select-form. Lets say we got search-option "**user by name**", we would go with:

```
$data = $database->select("account", [
"user_name",
"user_id",
"phone",
"email",
"age"], [
"user_name" => $_POST['user_name']]);
```

Fine so far. Now we get the search option "**user by ID**". Every thing else stays just the same. So i need only the

```
["user_name" => $_POST['user_name']]);
```

to be like

```
["user_id" => $_POST['user_id']]);
```

Is there a way to change that without writing the whole statement again?

It is just a example. Moreover for my project i will need to change other options of the query like **update to insert** oder **different join-options**. But for the moment i am fine with an answer to that.

Anyway, what do you think about the Medoo-Class. Got any cool alternative Class-solutions for me? Basically i know how to work with SQL querys but getting stuff to the array at the end is always driving me crazy. So i would love to get stuff faster and easier with a class.

Thx a lot for your help!
Best, Lox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just change the $where array before running the query like that:

```
if ($type == 'id')
{
    $where = ["user_id" => $_POST['user_id']];
}

if ($type == 'user_name')
{
    $where = ["user_name" => $_POST['user_name']];
}

$data = $database->select("account",
    [
        "user_name",
        "user_id",
        "phone",
        "email",
        "age"
    ],
    $where
);
```